# Nil is not compatible with expected dictionary value type 'Any' swift

Tags: ios, swift

Please let me know how to pass `nil` ? Because backend not allow me to send empty string that's why I'm trying to send `nil` instead of empty string.

```
let params: [String : Any] = [
    "billRefNumber": billPayment.billRefNumber!,
    "custRefNo": nil,
    "billAmount": billPayment.billAmount,
    "charges": billPayment.sendCharges!
]
```

But found following warning when I'm trying pass `nil`.

> Nil is not compatible with expected dictionary value type 'Any' swift

If I changed, `let params: [String: Any?] = [`

[image]

Comment: I've tried as much as possible by googling. But all are failed. Can u check my question again instead of pressing `Close`?

Comment: Why not simply omit the `custRefNo` key and `nil` value?

Comment: Pass `NSNull()` however this looks like a weird backend requirement.

Comment: You haven't shown enough code for anyone to understand the problem. Post a sample that people can paste into their projects and compile, and see the problem for themselves.

Comment: But I did try to check your code. As indicated by @uhuru, the first problem is that you need `Any?` in `params` if you're going to pass `nil`. As for the second error, I think it's a different issue. Notice the little red line in your image. I'd say the problem has to do with the call to `executeBillPayment()`. But I don't know anything about that function, so I can't help. Post more code, enough for people to effectively analyze your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try with

```
let params: [String: Any?]
```

Comment: if I did so, got above warning. Please check my question. I've edited.

Comment: I see. No idea how can you pass nil to the param then... Wait for someone with more knowledge. But in the meantime try to set it back to String: Any without the question mark and change the nil to a NSNull.self like this:
                "custRefNo": NSNull.self,

Comment: How are you sending the data to backend ?. Is it through query params or Http Body ?

Comment: Instead of NSNull.self like i told you on the above comment try NSNull(), i've been googling and I think it's better to use it this way.

Comment: @SHISHIRRAMIN httpbody instead